24.04.01 Dark mode delay
On both my laptop and desktop installs of 24.04.01 I have dark mode enabled in settings as my default display.
However, on both, it takes a few minutes after boot up before dark mode is applied to system applications such as Files (Nautilus), System Monitor, etc.
They appear in light mode and I have to shut them and reopen them after 4-5 minutes to get them in dark mode.
Does anyone else have this issue? And can you fix it?
The desktop is running an old Acer Nitro N50-100 with an NVIDIA GTX 1050 Ti on driver version 535.
I'm not near my laptop but it's a Lenovo Yoga 9i with an RTX card in it.

consider installing preloadto speed up application load time. See item 3 in this itsfoss article for further information.

That seems to have helped a bit (although I can't decide whether it really has helped or I'm suffering from bias - but it seems to have). Thank you.

Thanks for the feedback. I've added preload as an answer and if you'd be kind enough to accept it, others with the same question will be able to find it more easily in the future.

Use preload to Speed up Linux.

Preload is an ‘Adaptive Read-ahead Damon’. Effectively what it does is
speeds up application load time by monitoring the software that is
loaded and used day to day, the software used most often, and cache
them in memory. If you have a lot of memory, you will notice things
will improve – for example, my work machine has 20gb of RAM, 7gb of it
is used by caches and everything runs nice and smooth. If your
computer needs the memory, space is made, so you will not lose out if
you have the average 4-8gb. The difference is certainly measurable –
from 20% to 60% improvement in startup times.

use sudo apt install preload to install.
This itsfoss article explains more (item 3) as well as other options to speed up Ubuntu.
further reference
